# Beginning Python 3: Is there a more efficient way to write these 3 lines for capitalizing all first letters of a file?

Tags: python

In Python 3, is there a more efficient (computing-wise or pretty-code wise) way to capitalize all the first words of a list in a text file as shown below?

```
# First letter capitalizer
fhand = open('lowercase list.txt')
for line in fhand :
    print(line[0].upper()+line[1:])
```

I want to know if there is a more optimal way to express this in python.

Comment: Oneliner, `print(*[l.capitalize() for l in open('lowercase list.txt').readlines()], sep='')`. This however makes the code harder to read, so I'm not going to post it as an answer.

Comment: You should use either `with` or `try-finally` when opening a file. See [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the same functionality using the in-built Python method [capitalize()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize).

You can then write the code like this:

```
# First letter capitalizer
fhand = open('lowercase list.txt')
for line in fhand :
    print(line.capitalize())
```

Edit: As noted by [@flakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3280538/flakes) you should take care to close the file once you're done processing it to avoid leaking the file descriptor. To maintain the original structure of your code you can just call `fhand.close()` when you are done processing the file:

```
# First letter capitalizer
fhand = open('lowercase_list.txt')
for line in fhand :
    print(line.capitalize())

# Possibly do more processing

fhand.close()
```

However, this isn't very pythonic and requires more careful effort on the part of the programmer to ensure you free the resource up properly. A better way to do this is via the `with` statement as [@flakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3280538/flakes) pointed out. Python will take care of freeing up the resource without you having to manually do so, and will even [free the resource properly if an Exception is raised](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

So the resultant code should look something like this:

```
# First letter capitalizer
with open('lowercase_list.txt') as fhand:
    for line in fhand:
        print(line.capitalize())
    # Possibly do more processing here and no need to worry about closing fhand
```

Comment: You should also use a `with`  statement when opening the file to avoid dangling file handlers. `with open('lowercase list.txt') as fhand: ...`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `capitalize()` method on each line to capitalize the first word only.

also for better resource management, `with` statement is preferred for handling file operations as it automatically takes care of closing the file when it's no longer needed.

```
with open('lowercase list.txt') as fhand:
    for line in fhand:
        print(line.strip().capitalize()).      

    #remove strip(), if your data doesn't have any trailing or leading whitespaces.
```

Note: The `capitalize()` method should not be used if you want to capitalize just the first letter of a string without converting the rest of the string to lowercase. The capitalize() method will always convert the rest of the string to lowercase.

```
"harshIT".capitalize() #Output: Harshit
"HaRsHiT".capitalize() #Output: Harshit
```

But the code you have written would return

```
HaRsHiT => HaRsHiT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# First letter capitalizer
fhand = open('lowercase list.txt')
for line in fhand :
    print(line.capitalize())
```